# How do I post images in chat?

Tags: support, faq

I want to post images in chat, but I'm not sure how to do it.  How can I post images to a chat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Step 1:

Find an image you want to share.  It can be on the internet, or on your computer.

## Step 2:

If it's an image from the internet, right click the image and choose `Copy image URL`.

If it's on your computer, skip to step 3.

## Step 3:

Click `Upload...`

[image]

Or if the image is on the web, simply paste the URL into the chat box and press 'send'.

## Step 4:

If the image was on the internet, click `from the web`. Then paste the image URL into the text box.

If the image is on your computer, click `from my computer`. Then click `browse...`. Next select the file from the file selection dialog.

## Step 5:

Click `Upload`.

Comment: Thanks to the power of one-boxing, if you have a link to the image you can just paste its URL in the big chat text box and press enter (after Step 2).